# Hosting a React app with React Router on a static server

Tags: reactjs, server, static, react-router, react-redux

**Situation:**

- I'm building a React app with React Router.
- It was generated from `create-react-app`.
- I need to host it statically.
- If I visit the home page first and then click around, everything works fine.

**Problem:**

- When visiting a sub page directly such as `https://www.example.com/path/page` server returns `404` error because `/path/page` is not a valid directory on the server.
- For as far as I can tell, the server is just serving up files statically, and I cannot change how the server is written (I know I could solve this problem by routing all accesses to the react app with some server code, but this is not an option).
- How can I make all urls directly visitable by only changing code in my react app?

Comment: i believe if you user hash routing it would solve ur issue but i believe it is not good seo

Comment: what virtual host do you use?

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam Thanks for the comment. Yes I believe that would work but yea, it's not the best option..

Comment: @RitoTombe I actually don't know, since this is all on a client's server. I have no control over it. I can only change the frontend code.

Answer (score 3):

After some research, I figured out that what I needed was a **static site generator**.

There are a couple of options available that works with React.js

- React Static
- Gatsby
- Next JS

Some useful articles on getting started:

For Gatsby: https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/gatsby-static-site-generator-for-react-introduction-b9fce7df6b24

For React Static: https://medium.com/@tannerlinsley/%EF%B8%8F-introducing-react-static-a-progressive-static-site-framework-for-react-3470d2a51ebc